# Hbase Non Resolvable POM Error

Tags: maven-2, hbase

I downloaded Hbase code from Github, as soon as I imported the project as MAVEN Dependence I am getting the following error

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Project build error: 'parent.relativePath' points at org.apache.hbase:hbase instead of org.apache:apache, please verify your project structure
    - Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.apache:apache:pom:12 from htts://repository.apache.org/content/
     repositories/releases/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of apache release has elapsed or 
     updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:12 from/to apache release ://repository.apache.org/content/
     repositories/releases/): null to ://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/apache/12/apache-12.pom and 
     'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

Let me know if anyone of you have faced such an issue.

Regards

Santosh

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only downloaded part of the code - it has dependency on a parent .pom that you didn't download